# Can OOP be used in Embedded C?

Tags: c++, c, oop, embedded

I'm very new to software development and really loving it.
Currently, my work involves C++ programming in an OOP implementation (basically, the guys who started the framework for the software used OOP approach in everything). I jumped in and inherited what's already there.

Hobby-wise, I would like to develop a framework also for an embedded application.
Basically programming Embedded C on a microcontroller.
Is it wise to do the framework in OOP approach also?
I was thinking it is more organized.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. What language are you talking about? And there is no language "Embedded-C". The C++ standard also does not define an "Embedded C++" - this was an approach by (mostly) japanese companies around 2000, but never became widely used or a standard.

Comment: As given now, your question is unclear. However, Even if I assume you picked one language, it would still be primarily opinion-based, making it off-toppic.

Comment: sorry, noob here. what i mean is that the traditional C vs C++

Comment: but, thanks for taking time to answer this question.

Comment: My own two cents: (1) OOP is a valuable design strategy even in very small systems. (2) C++ is unusable on large computers, and worse on small ones. So yes to OOP, no to C++. Unfortunately, current implementations of Go are not available for small systems or I'd recommend that.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: I agree. That's why I use gcc with plan9-extensions. Imho a good compromise. The newer languages are still not stable enough (syntax, semantics). Although I think Rust might be more interesting than Go for embedded (just my opinion).

Comment: not sure that I can use OOP with C. all this time I thought OOP is just for newer languages like C++. (well, I saw in some Perl development that OOP can be used). I was always think that OOP is only needed for huge, huge projects...

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it depends on your microcontroller specifications (and how many resources you have).

In my experience (as Olaf says it's a subjective opinion):

- OOP approach is usually clearer, avoids some mistakes for common variables and allows other person to use the framework without a painful learning process.
- However... it usually require more resources as you need to encapsulate everything and that leads into more functions.

So... it depends...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on your Embedded applicaton.
In some scenarios some c++ features costlier.
for e.g. run time polymorphism. . 
Hope this link helps.!

http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4424383/A-guide-to-C--for-C-programmers

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: He doesn't have enough points to comment. But yes you are correct.